# Is there a law requiring a landlord to respond to rental agencies request for information in regards to previous tenants?

Tags: united-states, rental-property, landlord, tennessee

I have left a rental and have been trying for over 3 months to gain housing through other rental agencies (first and second month I was still at the property). The last place I have applied for notified me that the previous landlord isn't responding to any form of communication (call,text or email). This in turn is stopping my packet from being processed and approved and in turn the places I apply to are taken by other people. This is effectively not allowing me to get a place to stay. I think he is doing this purposely because I refused to stay when he wanted me to take a $200 increase in rent. So I wonder if this is legal or not. And if it makes any difference at all I am a vet that was medically discharged.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if there was such a law. Giving false information would be illegal. Not giving any — wouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a law requiring a landlord to respond to rental agencies
> request for information in regards to previous tenants?

No. There is no such law.